# Why do I have to log in separately for some of the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

Even when it shows up on my "communities".

I didn't have to do this before. It used to work properly.

Like I have 138 points on Super User, but when I go there I am prompted to log in or sign up.

Comment: If it works as intended [Universal Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) should create cookies for each domain in the SE network once you logged in on any of the sites. This does rely on your browser allowing these cookies to be stored. I do recall Safari wasn't too happy with those kind of cookies. It might be that more browsers or your local security settings prevent this from working as designed. But to diagnose you'll need to include the browser you use, any console log messages and relevant (failed) network calls.

Comment: I am using Chrome 57.0.

Comment: *But to diagnose you'll need to include  any console log messages and relevant (failed) network calls* Use the developer console of Chrome to include that.

Comment: The good news is that it seems to work now. I had to recover my account at Super User, but all other sites seem to work. Thanks for your help.